# Defining the (alias) name of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I've been looking over some code in an old Classic ASP system of ours that builds its own SQL within the stored procedure and then executes it *{shudders}*.

Several of the `SELECT`ion lines contain an assignment, similar to:

```
SELECT 
    my_field = CASE WHEN value = whatever THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ...
```

Is there any difference (or anything I need to be aware of) between this and using a standard `AS` alias?...

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN value = whatever THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS my_field
    ...
```

Comment: `AS` is a ANSI Standard Syntax & would wok almost in all DBMS.

Comment: Aaron Bertand has a great read on this topic. https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases

Comment: @YogeshSharma - That's what I suspected.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SeanLange - thanks Sean, will have a look.

Comment: @SeanLange - Yeah - interesting read. I'm genuinely surprised that Aaron uses this, but his choices as to why are clear. Personally, I find either way reasonably readable, as modern editors tend to colour the code anyway, and after years of reading good and bad SQL alike, I've become used to looking to the end of the line for the alias. As Mr Bertrand says - it's pretty much personal preference.

Comment: @Paul I first read that blog several years ago and thought at the time he was nuts. AS is the only ANSI compliant way. And if you read the comments there are plenty of well respected folks who make that argument. But Aaron refuted with many of the same arguments I make about ANSI compliance. Basically that portable sql is a myth, and rarely if ever needed in the real world. So I decided to take a walk on the darkside and coded a couple project using =. I agree with Aaron that it makes things a lot easier to read once you get used to it. Finding a column in a select is a LOT simpler. My 2¢

Comment: @SeanLange - One thing that did cross my mind about the argument (*portable SQL is a myth*) is that, until RDBMS systems fully implement the standard, it will always be a myth. However, I'm quite happy to follow the ANSI standards for now, despite the slight readability problem (though it could be argued that most SQL editors do allow the user to tabulate the code into columns, etc, making the code easier to read, also - though a lengthier process overall).

Comment: @Paul ANSI compliant code is fine but to say that you will use ANSI code is crazy. Every DBMS had dialect to do certain things far easier (or sometimes even outside) than ANSI code. In my 20+ years I have changed databases exactly never....meaning any effort at portable code would be a total waste of effort on my part. And if you do ever have to change the DBMS ANSI compliant sql is the least of your worries.

Comment: @SeanLange - We've had Oracle (some time ago), currently we have SQL Server and Informix, though Informix is going and Oracle is coming back. We have a few *interesting* other databases and hundreds of feral Microsoft Access databases... I do know what you're getting at, but if I can write one script that work across multiple DBMSs, then I consider that a plus. Don't get me wrong, the level of ANSI we're talking about scratches the surfacetypical CRUD stuff. Usually the deeper stuff *has* to be specific to the DBMS anyway. Perhaps I was broad-brushing by saying what I said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the following code is all synonymous:

```
SELECT one = 1;
SELECT 1 one;
SELECT 1 AS one;
SELECT 'one' = 1; --this is deprecated, don't use it.
```

Which you use (apart from the last), is normally down the preference. Personally, I use `AS`. One reason is I can then easily tell queries that return datasets, and those that assign values to variables a part.

Comment: I thought this would be the case, but better safe than sorry!  I tend to fully qualify with `AS` also, at least it's easily identifiable then. Thanks for your help, Larnu.

Comment: You can also use `value [alias]`

Comment: @JoePhillips that's basically the same as `name alias`. I didn't bother using any of the quoted versions, as you also have `name 'alias'` and `name "alias"`.

Comment: @JoePhillips - yes, I know; it ain't shortcuts using AS - fieldname [AS] alias.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 examples that you have given are identical. However, when you go through the old code you might also find a variant with an @ sign before `my_field`, like this:

```
SELECT
    @my_field = CASE WHEN value = whatever THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

In this case a varable called `@my_field` is assigned a value, but nothing is SELECTed. This you can not rewrite to the other syntax using `AS @myfield`.

Comment: No - I'm not interested in assignment to declared 'variables' or return parameters within SQL Server, simply the aliasing of the field. Thanks for your input, though, Morten.